# Range or missing - ElasticSearch - Query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, kibana-6

I'm currently trying to get the following logic into an ES Query - does `http_code` exist? if so, it should be between 400-600; but it can also be missing.

The following query doesn't work, I believe it needs to be altered and corrected.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "http_code": {
              "gte": 400,
              "lt": 600
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "http_code"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The original requirement is to save a filter in a **Kibana** dashboard with range 400-600 OR it's missing.

Comment: Have you tried removing the 2nd block in `must` query? what does it return?

Comment: It returns the range 400 to 600, but I also want the records that have the field missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the query that you've suggested you need to do something like that:

`The original requirement is to save a filter in a Kibana dashboard with range 400-600 OR it's missing. as:`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "http_code": {
              "gte": 400,
              "lt": 600
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "http_code"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask you if you ever had a filter set with something similar, and then a gauge that filters out `http_code` 500-600; which will override this query, and won't show the records missing the `http_code`; is there a way around it?

Comment: You can add as many conditions for your search as you require. The example your asking for, I should try adding a must part on your bool query with http_code.range from 500 to 600 and exists.http_code

In other hand, I guess you would remove your exists query if your http_code it's already btw 500 to 600.